# Flash game - returning to main menu

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, flash

I am working on a flash game and about finished with it but I'm running into an issue. When the game ends, or the user presses the "End Game" button I want to return them to the main menu. The game is set up so that the main menu is on the 3rd frame, and the game runs in the 4th frame. All of the game code is there.

A few things I have tried:
I just simply tried to return to the 3rd frame. This results in the error:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at Hundred_fla::MainTimeline/GotoEndGame()[Hundred_fla.MainTimeline::frame5:66]
```

I have tried returning all the game vars to their default values, removing all children... so on... I also get the exact same error... not sure what the problem is. I thought one solution would be to reload the movie, but this will be running on Android/IOS and I cannot refresh a webpage. ... any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Edit: The code on line 66 is:

```
while(stage.numChildren > 0){
    stage.removeChildAt(stage.numChildren-1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should lock stage link before trying to purge it of objects. You are seemingly removing the instance that runs the code, so it loses stage reference.

```
var theStage:Stage=stage;
while(theStage.numChildren > 0){
    theStage.removeChildAt(0); 
    //you can always be sure that element at [0] exists, rather than going for [numChildren-1]
}
```

Comment: That seemed to fix it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what's line 66 of the 5th frame, it could a few things:

- you are targeting Flash Player 9, where the display objects are loaded asynchronously to your gotoAndStop call, so you end up with null references. Solution is to target Flash Player 10 or 11 (change it in Publish Settings [Ctrl+Shift+F12]). If you really need to target Flash Player 9, there are [convoluted methods to ensure the attributes are accessible](http://www.lecrabe.net/wordpress/?p=42)
- after the `gotoAndStop` you are referencing an object from the 5th frame, which is not available anymore, and thus throws a null object reference error
- it's an error in your logic and we need to see some of the code to find it

When in doubt, it's always best to leave the `gotoAndStop` call as the last one in the method.

Edit:

After seeing the code, it seems that `stage` itself is null and thus throwing the error. If it makes no visible difference, you can surround your code with a try/catch:

```
try {
    while(stage.numChildren){
        stage.removeChildAt(0);
    }
} catch (error:Error) {
}
```

Also try listening to the `ADDED_TO_STAGE` event to make sure you have a valid reference to `stage` before accessing it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The code at 66 in that particular has been added to the post. I see that I dont get any errors when I build for flash 10+ but I need to build it AIR for IOS and Android. which results in the error :-( Currently the only code in the endgame method is the code starting on line 66 which i added above. Thanks again, i really need help on this one!!

Comment: I think this is a case of the second issue. Have you tried putting this code *before* you move the frame head with the `gotoAndStop`?

Comment: well the problem is that i get the error even with the gotoAndStop call commented out. but either way I have tried it with the gotoAndStop as the last line in the method.

Comment: Oh and a correction to the above. I see that in flash 10.3 I still get the same error, it is just not a "show stopper" rather it only displays in the output window...